# Can you cite a source in the introduction of your paper in MLA?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, mla

I'm currently writing a paper in a class about writing papers (go figure) and I'm stuck on whether or not I can cite something in the introduction. I can't find anything concrete on whether or not it was allowed.

Comment: Do you mean give cite something in the text of *your* introduction or cite something from some other work's introduction?

Comment: Citing something in the text of my introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *MLA Handbook* (8th ed.) does not mention the use of citations within introductory text at all.

Barring their proscription, I can only assume that the rules for such in introductions are the same as for anywhere else in the body of a piece of text.

Unless a publisher says not to do it because of their own house style, I see no reason why you shouldn't.